# How make endless loop between functions using Kotlin for Java in Android?

Tags: android, loops, kotlin

```
package com.example.flashlight

import android.content.Context
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var flashLightStatus: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        openFlashLight()

        while (true) {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                //Do something after 100ms
                closeFlashLight()
            }, 5000)
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                //Do something after 100ms
                openFlashLight()
            }, 5000)
        }
    }

    private fun openFlashLight() {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
        if (!flashLightStatus) {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)
                flashLightStatus = true

            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)
                flashLightStatus = false
            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        }
    }

    private fun closeFlashLight()
    {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
        if (flashLightStatus) {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)
                flashLightStatus = false

            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)
                flashLightStatus = true
            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This now just open the flashlight on the phone and the flashlight stay open all the time because the `while(true)`

```
while (true) {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                //Do something after 100ms
                closeFlashLight()
            }, 5000)
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                //Do something after 100ms
                openFlashLight()
            }, 5000)
        }
```

but if I'm removing the while true and doing only:

```
openFlashLight()
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            //Do something after 100ms
            closeFlashLight()
        }, 5000)
```

This will open the flashlight and will wait 5 seconds then will close the flashlight.
But I want to make something endless that it will open the flash light wait 5 seconds close the flashlight wait 5 seconds open the flashlight wait 5 seconds close.

That way nonstop.  Open/close each 5 seconds nonstop. That's why I tried to use the `while(true)` but then the flashlight just keep staying open nonstop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to repeat the flashlight on/off cycles every 5 seconds you can do something like this:

1. Keep a boolean flag as a class member:

```
var flashLightOn = false
```

2. Make a method that start the flashlight

```
fun startFlashLight() {
    openFlashlight()
    flashLightOn = true

    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.postDelayed(object: Runnable() {
        override fun run() {
            if (flashLightOn) {
                closeFlashLight()
            } else {
                openFlashlight()
            }
            
            // Changing the toggle and calling the same Runnable again after 5 seconds
            flashLightOn = !flashLightOn
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
        }
    }, 5000)
}
```

3. To stop this handler call: `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using kotlin coroutines

```
  val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

    scope.launch {
        while (true) {
            openFlashlight()
            delay(5000)
            closeFlashlight()
            delay(5000)
        }
    }
    runBlocking {
        delay(Long.MAX_VALUE)
    }
```

and also add this dependency in the build.gradle module level file

```
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9")
```

And if you want to do it using handler you can try this I am not sure if this will work or not.

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
var isFlashlightOpen = false

val toggleFlashlight = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        if (isFlashlightOpen) {
            closeFlashlight()
            isFlashlightOpen = false
        } else {
            openFlashlight()
            isFlashlightOpen = true
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
    }
}

handler.postDelayed(toggleFlashlight, 5000)
```

Comment: Your coroutine example is wrong.  It needs to check for cancellation or it will never end.  You would also never do runBlocking there, you would launch the coroutine and there's no need to do runblocking.  And if its on the main thread like the original example, a runblocking would freeze the app and cause an ANR.

Comment: @GabeSechan ya I also realize later that the runBlocking is not needed but i think the scope.launch would do the required work , how would we check for cancellation?

Comment: change the while loop to while(isActive).  This will cause it to check if it's been canceled and exit the loop, ending it.  This is important for any coroutine that has an infinite loop in it, because while the parent scope being ended will mark it as canceled, a thread in progress can't actually be safely stopped.

Comment: @GabeSechan that’s not necessary. Every suspend function you call that cooperates with cancellation (including `delay()`) give an opportunity for the coroutine to be torn down if it is cancelled. Most (all?) suspend functions in the core library cooperate with cancellation. They each mention their “prompt cancellation guarantee” in their docs that describe this behavior. (`suspendCoroutine` is an exception but I think it’s part of the standard library, not the core coroutines library, which has the cooperative `suspendCancellableCoroutine`.)

Comment: @Tenfour04 It is necessary.  What if the first line of my coroutine takes a semaphore, and another one is blocked on it?  You cannot cancel a coroutine arbitrarily, just like you can't cancel a thread arbitrarily.  Doing so is inherently unsafe, and can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @Tenfour04 See also https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html  Unless you're claiming the delay will throw when canceled and be silently caught and ignored.  But if so that is a god awful system that will only cause problems, I'm assuming the kotlin devs know basic concurrency.  It also wouldn't solve the problem

Comment: @Tenfour04 AZnd even if that is the case it still ought to be pointed out that you need to check for cancellation, because if that was a calculation rather than a call to delay it would never be cancellable.

Comment: Kotlin coroutines method of handling cancellation involves throwing CancellationExceptions and ignoring them, yes. These functions immediately throw a CancellationException as the means of providing prompt cancellation. It bubbles up to the top Job and is treated specially. It is kind of insane. I don't know why they designed it that way. You can break proper cancellation by catching CancellationExceptions. But you can see that checking `isActive` is unnecessary: https://pl.kotl.in/1R-FEdE6c In this case, the delay is intentionally a delay, not a calculation, so it's fine.

Comment: @GabeSechan Example with mutex. https://pl.kotl.in/jFNP7bA0P Am I missing something? I don't know a lot about concurrency design beyond using coroutines and executors at a high level.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Your example might work, but only if withLock is written carefully to catch an exception and release the lock.  In general, you CANNOT cancel asynchronous execution non-cooperatively and safely.  It's not just mutexes, it's any resource, or any state that changes and needs to be released or sent back.  Lock files, file pointers, etc.  Any non-atomic operation.  If you have a class where you have to make 2 function calls on it and it cancels inbetween them, the class can be in an undefined state.  In general, you do NOT want to autocancel anything.

Comment: Are you saying Mutex is broken as written by the Jetbrains authors? Shouldn’t try/finally handle the other situations you’re talking about? Coroutines is designed such that you cannot prevent it from exiting at any suspend function call in the event of cancellation unless you’re using try/finally. It’s all described in the docs you linked. Also an example of using a suspend fun instead of isActive to exit a loop.